# Creating dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC3 using Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating a User Registration form in ASP.NET MVC3 using razor view engine. I am facing problem to create a dropdownlist for country. Country list come from xml file.

My project hierarchy is as follows

**BusinessLayer  -> User_Account  -> Account_Registration.cs**

This is a class library in which I want to create a Model for user registration. The code for user model is as follows

```
public class Account_Registration
{
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
    public string User_EmailID { get; set; }
    public string User_Password { get; set; }
    public string User_RePassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime User_BirthDate { get; set; }
    public enum_Gender User_Gender { get; set; }
    public string User_Address { get; set; }
    public string User_City { get; set; }
    public string User_State { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> User_Country { get; set; }
    public string User_WebSite { get; set; }
    public string User_Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to know that where I should put country XML file and how can I create dropdownlist for XML file.
My Xml file is as follows

```
<countries>
      <country code="AF" iso="4">Afghanistan</country>
      <country code="AL" iso="8">Albania</country>
      <country code="DZ" iso="12">Algeria</country>
</countries>
```

As I have to deploy this project on IIS so I want to know where should I put xml file so that I can access it in Account_Registration model which is in class library project and how to create dropdownlist for population countries.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just import the xml file into your database?

Comment: Import xml in table or content only

Comment: Do you have a repository?  Write a method in your repository that deserializes the XML file and returns a `List<SelectListItem>`.  Better yet, put the countries in the database, as @MystereMan suggests.

Comment: how to create a repository. Please let me know how to create it

Comment: What are you using for your Business Layer?  EF?  Linq to SQL?

Comment: I am using EF in business layer

Comment: Then your repository methods sit between EF and the controller.  If that's what your business layer is doing, you can put the new method there.

Comment: cache the country list as Dmitriy Reznik - go through my tutorials   [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
  [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx
See my MVC 4 mobile tutorial for reading XML

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't read xml file each time you render registration page. That would be one little bottleneck you'd have since hard drive operations are costly. I'd recommend reading it into memory (like at the application startup once and somewhere into the global variable, e.g. Countries).

For rendering your list, I'd recommend looking at the [following](http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/tip-of-the-day-208-asp-net-mvc-populating-dropdownlists-using-linq-to-sql/) article. Basically, it goes like this:

```
 Html.DropDownList(“countries”, new SelectList(model.Countries), “CountryId”, “CountryName”))
```

Comment: It's a bottleneck because XML deserialization can be expensive.  If it were in the database, you'd still need to read it from the disk. :)

Comment: Not really. Databases can cache frequently-accessed data in memory for one and they use special techniques for fetching data from disk (more like finding data on disk) faster. Deserialization may be expensive and may be not :)

Comment: Well, yes, but you can cache the result of an XML deserialization also.  It really depends on what the OP is after.  If the OP wants to change the configuration via a text file, rather than building the infrastructure to maintain the database records in a form, an XML file might be appropriate.  Personally, I'd just add the records to a database table manually, and be done with it.

Comment: And I've just suggested caching xml results into the memory. :) Regarding database - agree.

Answer (score 0):

you can create own extension for DropDown.

```
public static class GridExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString XmlDropDown(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string value)
    {
        var document = XDocument.Parce(value);
        var model = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach(XElement element in document.Elements("countries/country"))
        {
            model.Add(new SelectListItem(){Text=element.Value, Value=element.Attribute("iso").Value})
        }

        return Html.DropDownList(name, model))
    }
}
```

So, on view you can use

```
Html.XmlDropDown(“countries”, model.Countries)
```